# Basic Datastage Transformer

Tags: datastage

i have a sequential file that has 1 column and 5 rows and i need to transfer it to different column. more elaborate explanation below:

```
INPUT DATA

Name:Xin tao ren  
COuntry:China  
Children:2  
Gender:Male , Age: 22  
ip address:192.168.0.1
```

i need to have a SAMPLE OUTPUT like this

```
Name        | Country | Children | Gender | Age | ip address
xin tao ren | China   |    2     |  Male|   22  |  192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pivot stage in a parallel job to convert rows into columns. Hope that helps!

Comment: The problem with a Pivot stage is that partitioning might place different input rows into different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes the groups of information always appear in the same order, and every set has six complete values.  Set up six stage variables, say svName, svCountry, etc., all type string and all initialized to "".  Derive the stage variables as follows:

```
svName  <--  If In.Line[1,5] = "Name:" Then Field(In.Line, ":", 2, 1) Else svName
svCountry  <--  If In.Line[1,8] = "Country:" Then Field(In.Line, ":", 2, 1) Else svCountry
svChildren  <--  If In.Line[1,9] = "Children:" Then Field(In.Line, ":", 2, 1) Else svChildren
svGender  <-- If In.Line[1,7] = "Gender:" Then Field(Field(In.Line, ":", 2, 1), ",", 1, 1) Else svGender
svAge  <--  If Index(In.Line, "Age:", 1) Then Field(In.Line, ":", 3, 1) Else svAge
svIPAddr  <--  If In.Line[1,11] = "ip address:" Then Field(In.Line, ":", 2, 1) Else svIPAddr
svLastInGroup  <==  In.Line[1,11] = "ip address:"
```

Use svLastInGroup as your output link constraint expression.
Map the other stage variables onto the appropriate column names.